# BufferedReader file not found

Tags: java, eclipse, file, ubuntu

This is my code snippet:

```
static String filepath = "test.txt";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
        String l = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(l);
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (No such file or directory)`
This is the exception I am getting.

What file path should I use? I put the text file in the `bin` folder.

I am running Eclipse on Ubuntu, it that matters.

Comment: Try put the file in where you run 'java', bin is in your classpath,to read it you may also use Class.getResourceAsStream()

Comment: You should have to include the file path in the FileReader. filepath is not a name of file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running eclipse and have a java project, then just put the file in the project and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Place the file at the root directory of the project folder. If your project root directory  is `FileReader`, then place the file into it